# Python dynamic import and changing a variable

Tags: python, dynamic, import, config, imp

Lets say I have the following config file:

**config.py**:

```
x = 2
y = x * 2
```

I would like to import this in the file **main.py**, preferably using load_source command, but I also want to be able to change the value of x at the time of import such that the change in x propagates to the other variables in the **config.py**. For example, I want the following code, prints 6 and not 4.

**main.py**:

```
import imp
config = imp.load_source('', 'config.py')
config.x = 3
print config.y
```

What is the best way to do that? I know I can write functions in **config.py** to do this for me, but I prefer the config to be simple variable definitions only.

Comment: Why not just import config and manipulate variable like that. Either way they're global

Comment: Even if you import it, the value of y will not change when you change x because it is defined after x, and the change of x, will not change the y, unless it is defined as a list or something

Comment: That is not how that works. Python uses dynamic casting when you say y = x * 2 that isn't a pointer. Meaning even in the script where y was defined if you print(y) then set x = 1 and print(y) again y will be the same. you could make y a function or create a class within config like brent suggested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the code into a class:

```
class Config(object):
    def __init__(self, x=2):
        self.x = x
        self.y = x * 2
```

Then, in your main program:

```
c = Config(3)
print c.y
```

Comment: I was hoping I could get away without defining class or functions, but yes it works, thanks.